# How I can do hosting my web app using node js with handlebars template engine on firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting, express-handlebars

Is there anyway to do hosting web app with nodejs and handlebars on firebase.In docs I cant find something about that. Also when I'm trying to do hosting it says that in public directory must be index.html,but in my app there are no html inside only handlebars.Thanks for help and sorry for language mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do firebase hosting with template engine, here is tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8